# In how many ways can numbers be arranged?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

There are nine (horizontally) contiguous square cells. We have numbers from one to nine. We have to arrange these numbers in the cells so that the sum of the adjacent three cells is completely divisible by three. How many ways can we do this?

[image: nine_horizontally_contiguous_square_cells]

(i could be wrong)I solved a part of it. 3, 6 and 9 are always divisible by three, so I can remove them. I'll just product the answer that I found at the end  to three factorial. Now I have a question for six cells.

the answer was given as follows: 6^4

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  What does "adjacent" mean here?  Perhaps it would help if you provided an example of a successful arrangement.

Comment: I shall add picture.

Comment: For instance, is this good:  $$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & 6 & 4 \\
9 & 7 & 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$?  all columns, all rows, and diagonals sum to $0\pmod 3$.  Is this overkill?

Comment: Whatever the rules, I would solve the problem assuming we had three each of $0, \pm 1$.  For each such pattern, you have $(3!)^3$ ways to populate the cells.

Comment: no, the alignment should be horizontal only

Comment: Ok. My hint still applies.  I don't understand the bit about removing those $\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Comment: That is, 3, 6, 9 are always divisible by 3, so we can ignore the their arrangement.

Comment: But that's wrong.

Comment: Note that specifying the first two entries determines the string.  Thus, starting with $1,0$ the string must be $1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,-1$.  Note too that you can't start with $1,1$ nor with $-1,-1$ nor with $0,0$.

Comment: numbers can be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: Again, it's easier to work $\pmod 3$ at first.  Three of your digits are $0\pmod 3$ and so on.  You can do the $\pmod 3$ count in your head, and then you just need to multiply by $(3!)^3$.

Comment: I don't understand, the numbers in the question are 1..9, but I can't give 0

Comment: Do you know what $\pmod 3$ means?

Comment: $(3,6,9)$ are all $0\pmod 3$.  $(1,4,7)$ are all $1\pmod 3$.  And $(2,5,8)$ are all $-1\pmod 3$.

Comment: 2 ( mod 3) = 2 I know that

Comment: One could also write $2\equiv -1\pmod 3$.  Personally, I think that clarifies things, but there is nothing wrong with using $(0,1,2)$ instead of $(0,1,-1)$.

Comment: can you please write the solution in order how to get the answer 6^4

Comment: the answer was given as follows: 6^4

Comment: My hints form a nearly complete solution.  I suggest studying them.

Comment: your solution: 6^3 but the answer is 6^4. If I'm wrong, please explain

Comment: My solution gives $6^4$.  I get six patterns, each with $(3!)^3=6^3$ ways to populate them.

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

We start by reducing $\pmod 3$.  There are three digits $\equiv 0\pmod 3$, and three each $\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 3$.  Thus, for any good pattern in $0,1,-1$ we have $(3!)^3=6^3$ ways to populate it.

How many such patterns are there? Well, any good string is entirely determined by the first two characters.  Thus $1,0$ would give the string $$1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1,0,-1$$

In principle there are $9$ ways to choose the starting two characters but three of these ($(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)$) fail to generate acceptable patterns.  The other $6$ all work (Note:  these correspond to the three permutations of $1,0,-1$).

Thus there are $6$ patterns, each of which can be populated in exactly $6^3$ ways, making the answer $6\times 6^3=6^4$ as desired.